# New Zealand Accredited Employer Visa - Transfer?

Tags: immigration, new-zealand

I'm presently being hired under the Accredited Employer Work to Residence Visa and am wondering if I am hired by another Accredited employer, do I have to resubmit an application or my existing visa can be carried over?